# How to show that a topological space $X$ having $X$ as the only dense subset of $X$ is discrete?

Tags: general-topology

How to show that a topological space $X$ having $X$ as the only dense subset of $X$ is discrete?

I don't know how to begin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint:** If $X$ is the only dense subset of $X$, then none of the sets $X\setminus\{x\}$ are dense for any choice of $x\in X$. What does that tell you about the closure of a set of the form $X\setminus\{x\}$? What does that, in turn, tell you about $\{x\}$?

Answer (score 2):

To prove $X$ is discrete, we need to show $\forall p\in X$, $p$ is open. That is to say $X-p$ is closed, but since $X-p$ is not dense, it is closed.